# Как сделать плавное раскрытие блока по высоте содержимого?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

При этом надо учитывать что экран будет сужаться и высота контента будет изменяться

```js
$('div').click(function() {
 $(this).addClass('q');
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.q {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat consequuntur ut, enim voluptate, optio quia quas neque commodi consequatur quibusdam necessitatibus vitae quam dolorum laboriosam, perspiciatis iste aliquid rem deserunt.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  autoHeightAnimate($(this));
});

/* Function to animate height: auto */
function autoHeightAnimate(element) {
  var curHeight = element.height(), // Get Default Height
    autoHeight = element.css('height', 'auto').height(); // Get Auto Height
  element.height(curHeight); // Reset to Default Height
  element.stop().animate({
    height: autoHeight
  }); // Animate to Auto Height
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat consequuntur ut, enim voluptate, optio quia quas neque commodi consequatur quibusdam necessitatibus vitae quam dolorum laboriosam, perspiciatis iste aliquid rem deserunt.
</div>
```